# Is there any way to change the text in an input field without typing it in manually?

Tags: python, tkinter

thank you for taking your time to check out my question! I was wondering if there is any way you can change the text in an input field in code? For example,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root)
e.text("Hello World")
e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you again for taking the time to check out my question!

Comment: If you read the documentation you will see there is a method named `insert`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Thank you! I will go read that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Entry.insert` method to add text to the input field, it takes 2 arguments, index and the text.

```py
e.insert(0, "Hello World")
```

And to delete, use `Entry.delete`, it takes first index and last index to delete

```py
e.delete(0, END)
```

[Documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/entry.html) for Entry